# some parts of the cloth simulation are protruding once collided with object

Tags: cloth-simulation

the cloth on some parts seems to be protruding once it collides with the object(Cube).

[image]
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your cloth settings would have been helpful... have you enabled _Self Collisions_ to prevent the cloth from intersecting itself?

Comment: That's what was missing. Cheers.

Comment: Well, it is disabled by default (I guess for performance reasons) but in almost every tutorial on cloth simulation it is among the first things that get changed in the cloth properties  :D